# using no namespace in xpath expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces

In an XSLT stylesheet, I have set `xpath-default-namespace` to match the input document that the stylesheet processes.  The output document is in the no namespace.

For example, the xsl:stylesheet element has xpath-default-namespace specified:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://my.example.com/"
>
```

Within the transform, I am building elements with no namespace, and I need to match on these elements as well.  For now, I use constructs such as:

```
<xsl:variable name="vCustomElement" as="element()">
   <some_element>
       <!-- element content -->
   </some_element>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:apply-templates select="$vCustomElement" mode="something" />

.
.

<xsl:template match="*:some_element" mode="something">
    ...
    <xsl:sequence select="." />
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

This works, but I am curious, is there a way for me to specify no namespace as a prefix in an xpath expression?  The above only works, as its matching all namesapces including the no namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT/XPath 3.0 you can write `match="Q{}local"` to match a no-namespace element, regardless of the current setting of xpath-default-namespace.

There's no way to do this in 2.0, other than resetting xpath-default-namespace, which you can do on any element with local scope.

Answer (score 0):

The following works, although, I am still curious if there is someway to specify the no namesapce as a prefix in the match expression

```
<xsl:template match="some_element" mode="something" xpath-default-expression="">
    ...
    <xsl:sequence select="." />
    ...
</xsl:template>
```